# Shopping cart price rule

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I need to apply a 60% discount to a maximum of ONE item from Category A, or its 6 subcategories. The discount will also to apply to any number of items from Category B.

The customer can order any number of items from Category A, but the discount will only apply to ONE item from Category A (or any of its subcategories).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Promotions => Shoppping Cart Price Rules => Add new rule,
- Fill in the Rule Name and description
- Select the Status, Customer Groups and if a coupon code is required
- Set the amount of uses per customer
- Fill in the From and To Date, as well as the priority
- Go over to the Conditions tab
- Click on the green plus sign to add a condition and from the drop-down select "Product Attributes Combination"
- You should now see a line that says "If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:"
- Click on the green plus sign right below and from the drop-down select "Category"
- You should now see a line that says "Category  contains  ..."
- Click on those 3 dots to bring up the category chooser and select your category (A and it's subcategories)
- Go over to the Actions Tab
- From the "Apply" drop-down select "Percent of product price discount"
- in the "Discount amount" field put in 60%
- And here's the crucial part, in the "Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" put in "1" so that the discount only gets applied to one of the items in the cart.

Comment: I already know how to do that. Your solution only allows me to get the discount on one item from Category A. I also need to get the discount on Category B with no quantity limit.

Comment: Create another rule for Category B with same discount

Comment: Like mageUz said just create a separate rule for Category B, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question

Comment: We want one coupon code to work for both categories. It needs to be ONE rule. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Haim's solution applies the discount if the qty of the cart item is 1. But if I add another item to cart with the qty of 1 the discount is applied again. The discount should be for a maximum of one but it is discounting two items.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution? I had to create two separate price rules for a particular customer group. The first rule applies a 60% discount to a certain category and does not require a coupon code. The second rule applies a 60% discount to any sunglass with a coupon code. The problem is that the rule with the coupon code needs to restrict the discount to one sunglass ONLY (this was set using the max quantity in cart), but it does not work. If someone adds quantity:1 for two different sunglasses, the coupon applies the discount to both of them. How can we fix this?